# Select и Update В одном запросе MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Требуется вывести данные status='unread' и сразу же обновить их на 'read'. Что я делаю не правильно?

```
    <?php 
       $host = 'localhost'; // адрес сервера
       $db_name = ''; // имя базы данных
       $user = ''; // имя пользователя
       $password = ''; // пароль
    
       // создание подключения к базе   
          $connection = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $db_name);
    
       // текст SQL запроса, который будет передан базе
          $query = "SELECT id,status,text_user s1 FROM datas WHERE status='unread'; UPDATE datas s2 SET status='read' WHERE s1.id=s2.id";
       // выполняем запрос к базе данных
          $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    
       // выводим полученные данные
          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
             echo  $row['status'];
          }
    
       // закрываем соединение с базой
          mysqli_close($connection);
    ?>
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: Но вообще лучше пользуйтесь PDO, mysqli мертво уже (почти)

Comment: Так запрос вообще нельзя писать.

Comment: @AndrewNikolaev Всё можно, если захотеть) Тут больше к правильности и целесообразности вопросы

Comment: Весьма странная задача. Зачем выводить то, что в момент вывода уже (процесс вывода на экран или куда оно там - занятие-то небыстрое) будет изменено? А вообще такие вещи лучше делать именно несколькими запросами, возможно, собранными в одну хранимую процедуру. Особенно в конкурентной среде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE temp_result (id INT);
INSERT temp_result (id)
SELECT id FROM datas WHERE status =‘unread’;
SELECT * FROM datas d
  INNER JOIN temp_result tr ON tr.id = d.id;
UPDATE datas SET status=‘read’ WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM temp_result);
DROP TABLE temp_result;
```

Необходимо сохранять промежуточный результат.

Comment: Мало опыта на MySQL у меня. А в нем как в MS есть временные таблицы или табличные переменные?

Comment: Временные таблицы есть, табличных переменных нет.